# plugin not working after child theme

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I have just installed a child theme of a twenty sixteen wordpress theme.

For some reason one of my plugins 'Jquery smooth scroll' no longer works. I tried alternative 'smooth anchor scroll plugins' but they neither work. Other plugins (like Jetpack, Theme my login etc) still work fine.

I would be very grateful for any help.

Jack

Comment: It's better either you post the errors you get or post the same question in the support forum of plugin. Be specific about what is the error so that it's easy to understand and answer. Since wordpress is a big platform, there can be a lot of complexities.

Answer (score 0):

A plugin isn't completely necessary for something like this.  If you're comfortable modifying your functions.php file, you can simply utilize [wp_enqueue_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) to load up a smooth scroll script such as [this one](https://github.com/cferdinandi/smooth-scroll).